# How can I reuse a view I built

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am a beginner on mobile dev and i am thinking about the structure of my iPhone app.
Its a social app and there is a profile menu like in instagram. Is there a way to create a view and extends it for the personal profile and the profile of other users. I don't want to duplicate the content in the tab view to build the same one in a modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Construct the view in a `.xib` file, which will be turned into a nib file in the running app. Each time you load that nib, you get new copy of the view (and all its subviews, of course).

Comment: I am going to google those keyword. I didn't know where to start to do such a thing but i didn't want to build a crappy app. Thanks !

Comment: If I then edit this xib, changes are done also on the different place i use it ?

Comment: My book teaches you about what a nib is and what you can do when it is loaded: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html