# Is there a way to create a header for multiple View Controllers in xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I need some help on creating a "Header" for multiple View Controllers without copy/pasting every time the line of code into the new view controller I create.
Something like creating a header in PHP and including it into the pages you want.

In the header I want to add custom text/data.

I tried creating a View on a single View Controller and then implementing that view on multiple storyboards, but it doesn't work and doubt that's the way of doing it.

I tried looking for something similar to what I needed but couldn't find it.
I am new to swift/xcode.

Thank you

Comment: Might be a duplicate of, say, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427910/how-can-i-reuse-a-view-i-built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create subclass of UIView with nib.
2. When adding instance of this view to view controller, also create
   constraints(or create them with interface builder).
3. Add setup
   method that takes String argument and sets the label outlet.

If you meant header that will push all the view controller content down, that's hard to implement and I don't advice it.

Answer (score 1):

> I need some help on creating a "Header" for multiple View Controllers without copy/pasting every time the line of code into the new view controller I create.

There are at least three ways to do this:

- **Common view:** Create a common view that you just add to each scene where you want the header displayed. RealNmae gives pretty good instructions for that, as does the [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427910/how-can-i-reuse-a-view-i-built) that matt linked in a comment, so I won't try to describe that approach again.
- **Inheritance:** Put the code to create the header in a view controller class that's otherwise empty. You might call it `HeaderViewController` or something like that. Then make all the view controller classes that need to display the header subclasses of that `HeaderViewController` class.
- **Containment:** Create a [*container* view controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html) that displays the header. Container view controllers can draw part of your UI, and then let a contained "child" view controller handle the rest. `UINavigationController` and `UITabBarController` are examples of container view controllers -- they draw a bar at the top or bottom of the screen that provides some functionality, and everything else gets drawn by the contained view controller(s).